# Problem using Response.Write to pass javascript that opens new browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following code to respond to click commands on a RadToolBar.  The switch part works fine.  Where I'm having trouble is with the Response.Write piece that is intended to open label.aspx?id=foo in a new browser window.  The label.aspx page is a simple page that generates and serves PDFs.  I think the code I've written is mostly correct.  However I must have missed some critical piece because when I run the app and click the toolbar button nothing happens.  Since the switch piece is working correctly and so is the label.aspx page, the problem mus be in this line here `Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('Label.aspx?ID=" + RadGrid1.SelectedValues["PackageID"].ToString() + "','_blank');</script>");` Any ideas?

```
    protected void RadToolBar1_ButtonClick(object sender, RadToolBarEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Item.Text)
    {
        case "Print Label":
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('Label.aspx?ID=" + RadGrid1.SelectedValues["PackageID"].ToString() + "','_blank');</script>");
            break;
        case "Request Return":
            //do something
            break;
        case "Remove":
            //do something;
            break;
    }
```

There are several other similar questions on SO.  I've looked at them all and they appear to recommend the same approach as I've taken above.  However, my code still does not work.

Comment: What do you see in the view source?

Comment: I'm not seeing any mention of the label.aspx page.  However, I would not expect to.  Response.Write is only called when there is postback containing the relevant command.

Comment: after Response.Write try to put Response.End()....

Comment: Well if your purpose is to open a separate window with the selected dropdown's value, you can do it all on the client side: `onclick="window.open('Label.aspx?ID=' + document.getElementById('RadGrid1').options[document.getElementById('RadGrid1').selectedIndex].value, '_blank');"`

Comment: That didn't work. (this was in response to 2GDev).

Comment: Good point Mrchief.  I had other reasons for doing it in the code behind but perhaps I need to reevaluate if that's truly necessary.

Comment: Right and I'm not saying that you can't make `Response.Write` work, its just that there are better ways to handle that. Glad you see it the same way.

Comment: I am still very curious though why Response.Write is not doing what I thought it would.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape some characters(single quote, double quote) in the string. Please try with this:

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">")
Response.Write("window.open(\'Label.aspx?ID=" + RadGrid1.SelectedValues["PackageID"].ToString() + "\',\'_blank\')");
Response.Write("</script>");
```